# How to style a tree using tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to style a tree into this form :

[image: goal]

but my code is in generate this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
        [level distance=10mm,
                every node/.style={fill=red!60,circle,inner sep=1pt},
                level 1/.style={sibling distance=20mm,nodes={fill=red!45}},
                level 2/.style={sibling distance=10mm,nodes={fill=red!30}},
        level 3/.style={sibling distance=5mm,nodes={fill=red!25}}]
        \node {31}
        child {node {30}
                child {node {20}
                        child {node {5}}
                        child {node {4}}
                }
                child {node {10}
                        child {node {9}}
                        child {node {1}}
                }
        }
        child {node {20}
                child {node {19}
                        child {node {1}}
                        child[missing]
                }
                child {node {18}}
        };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

How can I make the line begins from the center of the circle instead of the edge?

Comment: Sorry, but have you seen the example on the pgfmanual (version October 25, 2010) in page 218? I guess you derived the wondered image there, so please have look to the code: the style of the nodes (circular and red colored) is defined in the options of the `tikzpicture` environment.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino, I copied the code from `\begin{tikzpicture}` to `\end{tikzpicture}` and paste it into my tex file, but the line still begins from the edge, the result is different from the book, just like my picture, this is why I ask this problem here.

Comment: When I copy it into a document I get exactly that result: please, could you provide the code you used? I mean the `.tex` file starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino, code added.

Comment: It provides to me exactly the result shown in the pgfmanual.

Answer (score 6):

As **Alan Munn** mentions in his comment, the `tikz-qtree` package sets the anchor point of branch path to the bottom of the node, which is the most appropriate for linguistic trees; the following example shows this (the first tree) and also contains a modified version (the second tree) recovering the desired result by adding

```
edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode) to (\tikzchildnode)}`
```

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  level distance=10mm,
  every node/.style={fill=red!60,circle,inner sep=1pt},
  level 1/.style={sibling distance=20mm,nodes={fill=red!45}},
  level 2/.style={sibling distance=10mm,nodes={fill=red!30}},
  level 3/.style={sibling distance=5mm,nodes={fill=red!25}}
]
\node {31}
  child {node {30}
    child {node {20}
      child {node {5}}
      child {node {4}}
    }
    child {node {10}
      child {node {9}}
      child {node {1}}
    }
  }
  child {node {20}
    child {node {19}
      child {node {1}}
      child[missing]
    }
    child {node {18}}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=10mm,
  every node/.style={fill=red!60,circle,inner sep=1pt},
  level 1/.style={sibling distance=20mm,nodes={fill=red!45}},
  level 2/.style={sibling distance=10mm,nodes={fill=red!30}},
  level 3/.style={sibling distance=5mm,nodes={fill=red!25}},
  edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode) to (\tikzchildnode)}
]
\node {31}
  child {node {30}
    child {node {20}
      child {node {5}}
      child {node {4}}
    }
    child {node {10}
      child {node {9}}
      child {node {1}}
    }
  }
  child {node {20}
    child {node {19}
      child {node {1}}
      child[missing]
    }
    child {node {18}}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: `tikz-qtree` sets the anchor point of branch path to the bottom of the node, which is the most appropriate for linguistic trees.

Comment: @AlanMunn Thank you. I've added your comment to my answer.