# Example template for a hierarchy diagram

Tags: tikz-trees, trees

I wanted to draw a tree diagram so that i can put citations beside the node texts. Is there an example in code?

[image]

Comment: page 70 of the manual

Comment: Plus there are plenty of such diagrams here on the site.

Comment: [This answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83081/14) for example should get you started. You should use that and try to change and if you have problems, post your code and explain what's wrong.